# Mocking not able to mock method call

Tags: java, testing, junit, mockito

I am trying to mock a call in my test but I am getting a error as its calling the real method than mocking it.

This is my method

```
@Value("${omega.aws.nonprod-profile}")
private String nonProdProfile;

@Autowired
AwsService awsService;

public List<SecurityGroup> getAllSecurityGroups() {          
    AmazonEC2 ec2 = configSetter();     
    return awsService.getAllSecurityGroups(ec2);  
}

protected AmazonEC2 configSetter() {

    ProfileCredentialsProvider credentials = new ProfileCredentialsProvider(nonProdProfile);
    ClientConfiguration clientCfg = new ClientConfiguration();
    clientCfg.setProxyHost(this.proxyHost);
    clientCfg.setProxyPort(Integer.valueOf(proxyPort)); 
    clientCfg.setProtocol(Protocol.HTTPS);
    return new AmazonEC2Client(credentials, clientCfg);
```

}

Here is my test class

```
@InjectMocks
    private AwsConfigurationLocal subject;

    @Mock
    private AwsService awsService;

    @Test
    public void TestgetAllSecurityGroups() throws Exception {

        ec2 = Mockito.mock(AmazonEC2Client.class);
        securityGroup = new SecurityGroup();
        List<SecurityGroup> result = Collections.singletonList(securityGroup);
        Mockito.when(awsService.getAllSecurityGroups(ec2)).thenReturn(result);  
        List<SecurityGroup> actual = subject.getAllSecurityGroups();
        assertThat(actual, CoreMatchers.is(equals(result)));   
    }
```

The test actually calls the protected method configSetter and fails when setting a proxy. Help me understand what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: Can you provide the code for complete test class with top class level annotations?

Comment: @javaguy U mean autowiring AwsService in my subject class ?

Comment: Your test expects awsService.getAllSecurityGroups() to be called with yoyr mocked ec2 as argument. But your code doesn't call it with your mocked ec2. It calls it with the ec2 created by the call to configSetter()

Answer (score 0):

`subject.getAllSecurityGroups();` calls real `configSetter()` which returns real `AmazonEC2` which in turn is passed on to `awsService.getAllSecurityGroups(ec2);`. The parameter doesn't match your mock `ec2` so the default mock implementation is returned (I guess it's null) as a `actual`.

So the issue is: there is nothing that would prevent real implementation of `configSetter()` to be called.
If you annotate `subject` with `@Spy` and do

```
Mockito.when(subject.configSetter()).then(ec2);
```

it should work as expected.

That being said there's a lot of set up done only to check simple invocation being delegated. This is due intermixing of two responsibility in `AwsConfigurationLocal` - creation of `AmazonEC2Client` and providing `getAllSecurityGroups()`. If you move the former into separate class (let's say `AmazonEC2ClientFactor`) everything should fall in place.

Comment: Annotating with @spy and mocking `Mockito.when(subject.configSetter()).then(ec2);` had the same result. Its calling the real method. This class is for creating AmazonEC2Client  and getAllSecurityGroup is delegating a call to another class. I have this method configSetter as its a common method in this class.

Answer (score 0):

Try using powerMockito to return the mocked instance of `AmazonEC2`

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({AwsConfigurationLocal.class})//assuming this is your test class

@InjectMocks
private AwsConfigurationLocal subject=PowerMockito.spy(AwsConfigurationLocal.class);//or try Mockito.spy instead, whichever works

@Test
    public void TestgetAllSecurityGroups() throws Exception {

        ec2 = Mockito.mock(AmazonEC2Client.class);
        PowerMockito.doReturn(ec2).when(subject).configSetter().withNoArguments();
        //your code
    }
```